# Remove 'div' and 'span' on exporting dataTables to excel

Tags: html, excel, datatables, export

I am trying to export an HTML table using dataTables plugins. My table has div and span tags inside  td tag. While exporting the table, it is exported div and span tags as value. I tried to export only the value using the code

```
{extend: 'excelHtml5',
filename: 'Students with Accounts',
exportOptions: { format: { body: function (data, row, column, node ) 
{ return column === 4 ? "\0" + data : data;
return column === 4 ? data.text() : data; } } }
},
```

Still, I get the result as
[image: Screenshot of the exported Excel]

Is there any way to export only text of the cell?
Like this

[image: Desired result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you meant to use `node.innerText` instead of `data.text()`. See [innerText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText) - and `innerText` has to operate on the `node` not on the `data`.

---

But more than that, why do you need that `exportOptions` option at all?

The default behavior is to use [`stripHtml`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/buttons.exportData()) set to `true` - unless you interfere with that by doing what you try to do in your example code.

---

The key thing to remember is this: When you use:

```
body: function (data, row, column, node )
```

The `data` parameter represents the entire contents inside the `<td>` tag - including any HTML. By using some variation of:

```
return data
```

in that function, you are overriding the `stripHtml` default processing - and you will get the HTML in your Excel file.

From the DataTables documentation I already linked to:

`data` = The cell's innerHTML
`row` = Cell's row index
`column` = Cell's column index
`node` = The cell node (since Buttons 1.2.2)